# Aside element to go after a specified point

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

so, for aside, please see here what I mean: http://ejfox.github.io/sStory/

One article, 2 css columns, in the first column I have the article with text and pictures, in the second column I put aside elements. Those aside elements are either text or images and they resemble the asides of the newspapers.

I am using zurb foundation, so I created a row with two columns. I have the article in the first column. I would like to put asides in the second column, but only after a specified point.

For instance:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 

consectetuer adipiscing elit, 

tincidunt ut laoreet dolore [here]

magna aliquam erat volutpat.
```

I want the aside to go after the [here] position.

So, the question is, is it possible, using a 2 columns layout with zurb foundation, to put elements in the second column at points specified in the first column?

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward way of doing this in a way that will also give you predictable responsive behavior is to make a separate row for each paragraph you want the aside to relate to.

See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vr4C2/1/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-6 columns">
     <p>Story info relating to the aside</p>
  </div>
  <div class="large-6 columns">
    <h5>Aside</h5>
    <p>Your aside info</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank. But I am trying to keep the 2 columns as in one I am using markdown.